# How can I write Windows Phone app in Java

Tags: java, windows-phone-8

I'm sure it's possible, but how exactly am I able to write WP application in Java?

Comment: This is way to broad. You'll need to narrow this way down to avoid this from being closed. Also, searching for you exact title is a better way to get started: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+write+Windows+Phone+app+in+Java

Comment: What makes you think it *is* possible?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he's thinking to some Cross-Platform Frameworks..

Comment: I'm sorry, my question isn't precise, but fiskerXO managed what I was talking about. By "writing WP application" I meant some kind of Cross-Platform.

Comment: @Potek: Yes, but "I'm sure it's possible" doesn't give any evidence behind that "sureness". While Codename One looks like it *might* do this (the docs seem remarkably quiet about Windows Phone in many places) I wouldn't be "sure" that it's possible at all. I'd be interested in knowing exactly what they're doing... whether that's compiling the Java to IL or something else, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write WP applications in Java using multiple Cross-Platform Frameworks.

My suggestion would be to read something about : [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/download.html), which helps you writing Java Desktop Applications to Mobile Phones (iOS, WP 7.1/8, Android)

Comment: The fact that the FAQ talks about "Windows Phone 7 Coming SOON" is not particularly encouraging... the latest press release does indeed talk about WP8, but I'm failing to find anything explaining how it works at the moment, which is also a bit worrying.